# Shortest path between two points in a Grid (Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, shortest-path

I'm trying to find the shortest path between two points in a grid with no obstacles and move in all directions (N NE E ES S SW W WN).

It seems to be a common task... Is this not implemented already in Matlab? When Matlab plots two points joined by a line ( plot(X,Y,'-') ) seems to internally do this calculation as I guess that the generated image is a grid too.

Example: From [1,1] to [3,6] one solution is [1,1; 2,2; 2,3; 2,4; 3,5; 3,6]

I have tried:

```
    dist_x = length(linspace(p1(1),p2(1), dist(p1(1),p2(1))+1));
    dist_y = length(linspace(p1(2),p2(2), dist(p1(2),p2(2))+1));
    num_points = max(dist_x, dist_y);
    x = round(linspace(p1(1),p2(1),num_points));
    y = round(linspace(p1(2),p2(2),num_points));
```

But I think that it returns more points than it should and maybe there is an implemented routine.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't read that :)  You can (and should) edit the question and add the code.

Comment: do you mean something like [Bresenham line algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m)?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian That's it :) Bresenham line algorithm was exactly what I needed Thanks

Comment: @rauldg: Add it as an answer and accept it if it is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The solution (given by J.F. Sebastian) is the [Bresenham Line Algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m).

Comment: @J.F Sebastian Like this? Can't I vote your comment as correct answer?

Comment: J.F.Sebastian have to add the answer by himself. Then the answer can be vote and accepted, so J.F.Sebastian will get the points. Comment upvoting will not give any points. If you put his answer by yourself, he will not get any points.